# Terraform count condition ignoring second parameter vsphere provider

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-vsphere

I am trying to create a vm using count. So that, both conditions should be false for the  resource to be created.

**Main.tf**

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "ubuntu" {
  count             = !var.is_ubuntu && var.extra_disk_create ? 0 : 1
  name              = var.vm_name

#additional configuration

...
}
```

Doesn't matter if **var.is_ubuntu** is either false or true the resource will be create all the same.

am i missing anything here?

any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the explicit comparison:

```
 count             = var.is_ubuntu != false && var.extra_disk_create == true ? 0 : 1
```